# How can I let robots access my site?

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawlers

I have a webpage on my university's server, which means I cannot access the root directory and change files there.

Is there some other way to give access to robots to my page?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you specifically have evidence they're *not* accessing the page? Overall, spiders will crawl anything they can get at by default, with robots.txt generally used to *limit* that behavior, not the other way around. (It's the [Robots *Exclusion* Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt)) While what you're asking is possible, it's probably unnecessary, unless the university has a robots file set up blocking them, in which case you might want to inquire with them why that is.

Comment: @Su' - Yes, I know for sure they have no access.

Comment: @Pandora, how do you know? If you can see it in a browser then they should be able to see it, too.

Comment: @John Conde Incorrect. IE, Firefox, and other browsers are not robots; they do not check or obey robots.txt.  Whereas a bot like GoogleBot **will** check robots.txt, and obey it if it denies access. So it's entirely possible that Pandora can access the site's pages, but bots cannot.

Comment: @will if there is no robots.txt then they can. That seems to be the case here.

Comment: @John, for example via Google Webmaster Tools, or this site: https://www.changedetection.com/

Comment: @John I understood the question to mean that the university already has a robots.txt in the root folder which the original poster cannot change. Looking at it again, though, I see Pandora says "cannot ... **create**" a robots.txt. Perhaps I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Will - Yes, it was my mistake as I thought that the robots file can also allow robots to crawl the page. I suppose that the robots file was indeed created by the university on the root level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the meta tag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="all">
```

or you can go to [Google AddUrl](http://www.google.de/addurl/) and add your URL to Google. But when you have no good content on your site you don't get so much site so the index. In the last time its very important to place sites to google in a good position.

Before you should read some things about SEO optimizing.